# What projection is used when you apply an image to an SCNSphere?

Tags: scenekit

I have a texture image that is 1024x1024 that I use as the `sphereMaterial.diffuse.contents` applied to a `SCNSphere` which has `isGeodesic` set to true. This causes the image to be wrapped such that there is distortion at the poles (as I would expect).

The image is nothing more than blue on top and green on the bottom to produce a sky/ground metaphor. Now I would like to blit smaller images, 120x120, onto that to make a panorama. This works fine with plain bitting for things near the equator, but of course not for the poles.

So does anyone know exactly what projection SceneKit is using for spheres, and perhaps have pointers to information on how to work with it?

**Answer is:** Equirectangular